# difference in meaning between 'have + object + verb/ing' vs 'make + object + verb'?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, difference

Is there any significant difference in meaning between **have + object + verb/ing** and **make + object + verb**? I heard there is always difference in English words when compared to their synonyms. the same goes for my mother tongue and every other language too. but how different are they? can I use them interchangeably?

as in

> this video made me laugh

> this video had me laugh/laughing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference between *made me laugh* and *had me laughing.* (We don't say *had me laugh*).

However, *She made me wash the dishes* could imply that I was unwillingly compelled to do so, while *She soon had me washing the dishes* could refer to my allotted task as an employee or volunteer.

Comment: according to the second answer to the post here: [link](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/208233/have-somebody-do-something-vs-have-somebody-doing-something) There is a usage of **have somebody verb**. Is it only limited to 'laugh' that I can't use this structure?

Comment: Oh, oh, I forgot that Americans use _have someone do something_ to mean _cause them to do it_. (I still think that _it had me laugh_ is unidiomatic, though.)

Comment: That's interesting. Thank you!